# Reversing single table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, single-table-inheritance

I'm currently working on a little project and I crossed the following problem:

I have the following relations:

```
User (id, name)
User_car(user_id,car_id)
Car (id,name)
CarSeat (id,name,car_id)
OrderItem (id,type,item_id)
```

In my ruby code i implemented single table inheritance, users owns an entire car and also the car seat.

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_seats
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :order_items, foreign_key: 'item_id'
end

class CarSeat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  has_many :order_items, foreign_key: 'item_id'
end

#Single table inheritance     

class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.inheritance_column = :inheritance_column
end 

class CarOrderItem < OrderItem
  belongs_to :car, foreign_key: 'item_id'
end

class CarSeatOrderItem < OrderItem
  belongs_to :car_seat, foreign_key: 'item_id' 
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
  has_many :car_seats, through: :cars
end
```

This structure allows me already to extract a lot of useful information. However I was not able yet to determine a way to **extract all** order items referencing either cars or car seats **belonging** to a specific user. In order to have

User  -> has_many: order_items, through:[cars,car_seats]  (since those have both :order_items)

This would require to have something like:

OrderItem has_many: users (since a car can be owned by many users) but it want work because of the single table inheritance

Comment: It appears to me that you **disabled** STI, trying to implement a polymorphic association. Such a mess X)

Comment: Sounds like you're having issues in database design, what associations do you need, exactly?